# How to control value type of wParam in WM_IME_CHAR

Tags: winapi, ime

I'm working on a C++ program that receives user's keyboard input on Windows 10. Users can input English and East Asian languages like Chinese using Input Methods and US keyboard.

The program gets WM_IME_CHAR messages when a user types Chinese via a Microsoft Input Method. The wParam values it receives are very different on two Windows 10 computers, with same keyboard input and same Input Method selection by a user.

To make a test, a user enters a same Chinese character on a keyboard on the two Windows 10 computers. On one computer, the wParam gives a character with GBK or GB2312 encoding, which I know how to handle. On the other computer the wParam seems always a small number 63, which I don't know what it is. I can't find any differences between the two computers. As far as I know all other software works the same on the two computers. For example, NotePad works the same on the two computers.

My goal is not to find out the differences of computer settings. My goal is to fix my program so that it receives the same correct input from both computers even if they may have different settings.

What could affect the type of values in wParam of a WM_IME_CHAR message? How is it controlled via Win32 or Windows API C/C++ calls?

The program was built in Visual Studio 2019, targeting 32-bit (x86) platform. The particular IME used in the test was Chinese Simplified - Microsoft Pinyin.

Comment: How are you 'extracting' the character from the `wParam`? Maybe show us a code snippet of your message handler.

Comment: According to Microsoft documentation, wParam of WM_IME_CHAR is the character. The code to get a character from wParam in the message would be something like: unsigned ch = (unsigned) wParam;

Comment: It can be a one-byte or two-byte value. But we still need to see how you are casting/converting the `unsigned long int` value into a `wchar_t` (or whatever). That conversion, if wrong, could be causing undefined behaviour.

Comment: Also, what is your build system (compiler, target bitness, etc.)? What IME are your test beds using?

Comment: How to cast the wParam into a character and how it would be processed is not quite relevant to the question. The mystery here is why wParam of WM_IME_CHAR message gets 63 on a Windows 10 computer for different user inputs and what the number represents.

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2019, targeting 32-bit (x86). The particular IME used in the test was Chinese Simplified, Microsoft Pinyin.

Comment: Well, now that we see you're targeting 32-bit in your build, there may be a clue. If the Windows systems are actually 64-bit, then your program is running on WOW64 but the IME may not be. So, there will be a difference in size for the `WPARAM` type (it's a `UINT_PTR`, IIRC). That *could* be causing problems - I'm not sure how the WOW64 system 'marshals' messages from fully-fledged 64-bit programs. To repeat: We need more details ***in the question itself***.

Comment: The `wParam` is the actual character typed. "*On the other computer the wParam seems always a small number 63, which I don't know what it is*" - 63 is the ASCII code for the `?` character, which is what you get when a Unicode character can't be represented in a given locale.

Comment: The latest comment offers a very interesting clue although I don't have all the connections. The program was tested on 2 computers. On one computer the wParam gives GBK/GB2312 encoding. Is it possible something is preventing the other computer from sending the GBK/GB2312 encoding?

Comment: I'm adding some details as suggested by @AdrianMole.

Comment: Is your program Unicode or MBCS?

Comment: @DanielSęk thanks for the question. Investigated a little I believe it's MBCS. This is also based on my recollection among many documents I read so far that if the window class is registered by RegisterClassA() the window is not Unicode. The code calls RegisterClass() and I don't see definition of UNICODE macro. I think RegisterClassA() is called. Another clue is that on the "good" computer the wParam values are GBK/GB2312. The program is not Unicode. If you confirm this is what you look for I'd add to the question.

Comment: Never tried IME with MBCS, but it seems that two machines have different code pages set for non-Unicode applications. When compiling for Unicode, you get just Unicode codes. For MBCS that have to be converted leading to '?' characters for replacing nonconvertible codes.
I'm not sure for what you want to handle `WM_IME_CHAR`. Usually you can just use IME without additional code. Standard edit boxes implement even in-place preview. For custom ones more work is needed if you want to correctly position preview or implement in-place version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I investigated and tried various Windows API calls on multiple Windows 10 computers, and finally got a relatively complete answer with solution. I’m sharing what I have found.

When a user inputs Eastern Asian characters from keyboard via an IME, 3 factors can affect the values passed into your program via the wParam of WM_IME_CHAR message. The factors are:

- a) The setting of “language for non-Unicode programs” on the Windows
  10 PC
- b) How the window class is registered, by `RegisterClass[Ex]A()` or `RegisterClass[Ex]W()`
- c) How WM_IME_COMPOSITION is processed in
  your program.

Among the factors, the software developers have control over b) and c). With correct coding, b) and c) offer enough control to make your program work regardless of how a) is set.

The PC setting mentioned above can be accessed via the Control Panel. It is labeled in two ways in Windows systems, as “language for non-Unicode programs” in the display pane, and as "system locale” in the editing dialog. I believe the setting not only specifies a language but also implies a unique character encoding. This concept is important to Chinese language as there are several encodings around. This setting is system-wide, not per-user. To change it you need an admin password. If you change the setting the Windows system immediately asks for a system restart. To locate the setting, you either open Control Panel, then Region / Administrative pane, or open Settings, then Region / Time & Language / Region / Additional date, time & regional settings / Region / Administrative pane.

When the “language for non-Unicode programs” is set to an Eastern Asian language with an encoding that covers user’s input, and if your program registers the window class by `RegisterClassW()` or `RegisterClassExW()`, the wParam of WM_IME_CHAR gets the Unicode of the input characters. If your program registers by `RegisterClassA()` or `RegisterClassExA()`, the wParam of WM_IME_CHAR gets the particular encoding selected by the “language for non-Unicode programs” setting.

When the “language for non-Unicode programs” is set to “English (United States)”, or any languages whose encoding does not cover the input, and a user enters Eastern Asian characters via an IME, the values in wParam of WM_IME_CHAR depend on how you register the class and how you handle the WM_IME_COMPOSITION message. If WM_IME_COMPOSITION is properly handled, and you register via `RegisterClass[Ex]A()`, the wParam gets the encoding of the IME. if you register via `RegisterClass[Ex]W()` the wParam gets the Unicode. Without proper handling of the WM_IME_COMPOSITION message, the wParam gets a “?” to indicate an error condition, regardless how you register the window class, by `RegisterClass[Ex]A()` or `RegisterClass[Ex]W()`.

To let your program work regardless of how the “language for non-Unicode programs” is set, you should handle WM_IME_COMPOSITION message properly. The simplest way to handle the message is to pass it to the `DefWindowProcW()` function.

Based on my tests, if you process WM_IME_COMPOSITION correctly, several other things commonly mentioned in forum discussions or articles do not matter.  It doesn't matter if you use `GetMessageA()` or `GetMessageW()`, nor versions of `DispatchMessage()` or `DefWindowProc()` (for all other messages). More importantly you do not need to set your project Unicode (no need to define UNICODE or _UNICODE macros). However if you set your project to Unicode, the `DefWindowProc()` will point to `DefWindowProcW()` which processes the WM_IME_COMPOSITION message properly.